# PHP Foreach Loop with If

Tags: php

Trying to loop thru a result that has items. Items have a type and trying to echo out the category title for each group. Normally this works excellent with one loop but the $item-type foreach I *Think* is throwing things off. Any solutions?

```
<h2>Package <?=$packages->id?></h2>

<?php foreach($packages->item as $item):?>

    <?php foreach($item->type as $type):?>

        <?php $subtype = null;?>

        <?php if($subtype != $type->name)?>

            <h3><?=$type->name?></h3>

            <?=$item->name?><br>

            <?php $subtype = $type->name;?>

    <?php endforeach;?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

DB structure:

```
items
    id   name
    1    mainitem1
    2    mainitem2
    3    item1
    4    item2
    5    item3
    6    item4

types
    id   name
    1    category 1
    2    category 2
    3    subcategory1
    4    subcategory2

item_type
    id   item_id   type_id
    1    1         1
    2    2         2
    3    3         3
    4    4         3
    5    5         4
    6    6         4

packages
    id   item_id
    1    1
    2    2

item_package
    id   package_id   item_id
    1    1            3
    2    1            5
    3    2            4
    4    2            6
```

What my result currently is:

```
package 1
    category 1
        item 3
    category 1
        item 5
    category 2
        item 4
    category 2
        item 6
```

Desired result:

```
package 1
    category 1
        item 3
        item 5
    category 2
        item 4
        item 6
```

Comment: can you `print_r($packages->item)` instead

Comment: preformatted its around 1000 lines

Comment: Add it to paste bin .. want to be sure of what am dealing with here

Comment: there is a syntax error in your code, in your condition

Comment: Why are you opening and closing PHP tags on every line?

Comment: @jocelyn so I can move things around and get it right before I make it a php block.

Comment: @dynamo from you code .. have been able to come of with the most likely possibility .. see below

Comment: pastebin here  http://pastebin.com/H4xCwbxb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$subtype` has no role to play since it was set to Null before the if statement

```
$subtype = null;
if($subtype != $type->name)  <------- This would always be true
```

Category Name is also duplicated since its in the inner loop instead of outer loop

This is all i think you need

```
printf("<h2>%s</h2>", $packages->id);
foreach ( $packages->item as $item ) {
    printf("<h3>%s</h3>", $type->name);
    print("<ul>");
    foreach ( $item->type as $type ) {
        printf("<li>%s</li>", $item->name);
    }
    print("</ul>");
}
```

Comment: This is still giving me the same result, check my comment above with my pastebin.

Comment: @dynamo let me work with your real objects then add `serialize($packages)` to past bin .. i would be able to work with your objects directly

Comment: Figured out my code does work correctly, just has to be a php block and not open/close each line. Going to accept because your code helped me figure it out.

Comment: @dynamo good to know .... but you don't have to write if else that way ... You need to make your code clean and readable

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to your above mentioned problem please refer the below code snippet

```
    <h2>Package <?=$packages->id?></h2> 
   <?php foreach($packages->item as $item):?> 
    <h3><?php echo $item->name;?></h3>

   <?php foreach($item->type as $type):?>
   <?php $subtype = null;?> 
   <?php if($subtype != $type->name)?> 
    <?=$type->name?><br> 
   <?php $subtype = $type->name;?> 
  <?php endforeach;?> 
  <?php endforeach;?>
```